# Configure a cron job to run only if laptop is plugged in?

Tags: laptop, cron

I'm setting up a cron job to update my nmzmail database periodically, but I'd like the cron job to execute only if my laptop is plugged in.  Is there a way to do this?  If there's not a built in cron command, then is there a way to check via the command line that I could use in a simple script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expand a bit on the first answer, and instead do something like this for a cron entry:

```
[ $(cat /proc/acpi/ac_adapter/AC/state | awk '{print $NF}') = 'on-line' ] && /path/to/your/script_file
```

I would rather not even start my script, unless the test is successful. In this instance cron will never start the script, if the laptop is on battery.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler version using awk :

```
[ $(awk '{print $NF}' /proc/acpi/ac_adapter/AC/state) = 'on-line' ] && /path/to/your/script_file
```

but this version still looks simpler IMHO :

```
grep -q on-line /proc/acpi/ac_adapter/AC/state && /path/to/your/script_file
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to check if /proc/acpi/ac_adapter/AC/state contains the word on-line.
You could put the following in at the beginning of your cron job :

```
# Do nothing when no AC power is available
grep -q on-line /proc/acpi/ac_adapter/AC/state || exit 0
```